# React Context and separate classes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've given up hope on getting mt head around Redux (I'm new to React), and see the Alpha version of React offers a new Context.

So I am attempting to learn it, and my goal is, I have a Navbar, which I want to respond to a state within my context, `{isAuthorised: false}`.

I'm following [this guys video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XLJN4JfniH4&index=1&list=WL&t=0s):

But he has all is code in a single file. I'm trying to do it 'right'.

What I did was created a folder called 'context' and within that, created a jsx called provider.jsx.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';


export default class MyProvider extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isAuthenticated: false
        }
    }

    render() {
        const MyContext = React.createContext();
        return(
            <MyContext.Provider value="Test Text">
                {this.props.children}
            </MyContext.Provider>
        )
    }
}
```

https://github.com/CraigInBrisbane/ReactLearning/blob/master/src/context/provider.jsx

In there, I created the context within the render (This might be wrong... maybe that's meant to happen in my App jsx?).

I create a state in there, defaulting isAuthenticated to false. (I'll add code later to set that to what it should be).

This compiles... and runs.

In my App component, I use my provider like this:

```
import MyProvider from './context/provider.jsx';


export default class App extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <MyProvider>
            <div>
                <Router>
                    <div>
                    <Navbar />
                        <Route exact path='/' component={Home}  />
                        <Route path='/about' component={About} />
```

https://github.com/CraigInBrisbane/ReactLearning/blob/master/src/app.jsx

So I am wrapping all my code with MyProvider.

In my Navbar component, I import my provider:

```
import MyProvider from '../../context/provider.jsx';
```

I then try and output somethign from my provider within my render:

```
     return (
    <div>
         <MyProvider.Consumer>
            {(context)=> (
                <p>Here I am {context}</p>
            )}
        </MyProvider.Consumer> 
    <nav className="navbar navbar-expand">
```

https://github.com/CraigInBrisbane/ReactLearning/blob/master/src/components/navbar/navbar.jsx

But this goes very badly for me.

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string
>   (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your
>   component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up
>   default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `Navbar`.
>       in Navbar (created by App)
>       in div (created by App)

And

> Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for
>   built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
>   but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from
>   the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named
>   imports.

How can I get this to work? Where should my .createContext reside?

[Code (With error) is here](https://github.com/CraigInBrisbane/ReactLearning).

Comment: Could you confirm it gets imported properly and do right after the import  `console.log(MyProvider)` .

Comment: If I add a log in my constructor of my Navbar, I get "f MyProvider(props) { _class.....". Is that expected?

Comment: Added link to my broken code, which might be easier to see.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I never did, @NSjonas - I’m not sure what I’m doing wrong but it seems I can’t get data in the child components.

Comment: @Craig for me I was getting this error when I was just using the wrong version of `react-dom`

Answer (score 6):

So the problem is that you export `MyProvider` and try to access static component on it - which is `undefined`:

```
console.log(MyProvider.Consumer);  // undefined
```

the `Consumer` is existing as a static property **only** in `MyContext` component.

What you need to change:

**provider.jsx**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export const MyContext = React.createContext();

export default class MyProvider extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isAuthenticated: false
        }
    }

    render() {

        return(
            <MyContext.Provider value={this.state.isAuthenticated}>
                {this.props.children}
            </MyContext.Provider>
        )
    }
}
```

then in **navbar.jsx**

```
import MyProvider, { MyContext } from '../../context/provider.jsx';

<MyProvider>
   <MyContext.Consumer>
      {(context)=> (
          <p>Here I am {context}</p>
      )}
   </MyContext.Consumer> 
</MyProvider>
```

take a look at [this tutorial](https://medium.com/dailyjs/reacts-%EF%B8%8F-new-context-api-70c9fe01596b).

**EDIT:**

To have the `Consumer` exist in `MyProvider` you would have to assign static variable on it that points to MyContext `Consumer`

```
MyProvider.Consumer = MyContext.Consumer;
```

Then I think you could use it like:

```
<MyProvider>
   <MyProvider.Consumer>
      {(context)=> (
          <p>Here I am {context}</p>
      )}
   </MyProvider.Consumer> 
</MyProvider>
```

However I'm not sure if it is a good idea.

Comment: Thanks Tomsz... I've made those changes and get no error now, but console.log(MyProvider.Consumer); returns undefined still. I've pushed my changes to my repo...

Comment: it **should** return undefined, because you do not have any static property defined on `MyProvider`. It exists only for `MyContext`.

Comment: In other words `MyProvider` is just a regular Component, not any way different from others.

Comment: Thanks @Tomasz ... But I just see "Here I am" at the top where I do the <p></p>. Nothing in context. Is that expected?

Comment: @Craig you should see the ‘value’ passed to the context. Maybe try ‘React.createContext(“my-context-name”);’

Comment: @Craig I'd really like to know if you got this working. I looked at the navbar component in your sample, I don't see it. Were you ever able to figure out how to share the context between your MyProvider and other components in other files?

Answer (score 2):

Was getting the same error...

Turns out I was using an older version of `react-dom`.  Updating it to `^16.3.0` fixed it for me!

Comment: This was the same problem I had

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XLJN4JfniH4&index=1&list=WL&t=0s) I was able to get it working. Here's my solution...

**AuthCtrProvider.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// create context blank, it gets filled by provider
export const MyContext = React.createContext();
// the state object is initially in the AuthCtrProvider and gets passed into the context
// via the value argument to the provider
export default class AuthCtrProvider extends Component {
    state = {
        isAuthenticated: false,
        counter: 100,
        doubl: () => { this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter * 2 } ) }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            // pass in this.state (which carries the data and the doubl func and also
            // pass in three additional functions
            <MyContext.Provider value={{
                state: this.state,
                toggle: () => { this.setState({ isAuthenticated: !this.isAuthenticated })},
                incr: () => { this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter + 1 })},
                decr: () => { this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter - 1 })}
            }
            }>
                // include the children that will be wrapped by this provider (in App.js)
                {this.props.children}
            </MyContext.Provider>
        )
    }
}
```

We export the MyContext and the default AuthCtrProvider. This is probably bad form here because I'm mixing a counter with an unrelated isAuthenticated. I'm just doing this to demo the functionality.
Also note - there's a function doubl in the state and there's functions in the provider that are separate from the state. Again, this is only used to make a point further down.

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AuthCtrProvider, { MyContext } from './AuthCtrProvider';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <Navigation />
                <AuthCtrProvider>
                    <MyContext.Consumer>
                        {(context) => (
                            <p>Counter from the context = {context.state.counter}</p>
                        )}
                    </MyContext.Consumer>
                    <header className="App-header">
                        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                        <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
                    </header>
                    <Main />
                </AuthCtrProvider>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

This shows the counter from the context.state so we can see it at the top level. In the project I have other imports for navigation and routing. One of my pages that loads in  is ProjectDetails.jsx...

**ProjectDetails.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
// in this file I only need to import the context
import { MyContext } from '../AuthCtrProvider';
// other imports for presentation components, OData, and such

    render() {
    return (
        <div style={{ display: "flex", flex: "1 1 0", alignItems: "flex-start", overflowY: "auto" }}>
            // we get access to the context using 'context' var but it can be whatever name you want
            <MyContext.Consumer>
                {context => (
                    <React.Fragment>
                        // note accessing the 'incr' function which is outside the state so it's just context.incr
                        <button onClick={context.incr}>incr {context.state.counter}</button>
                        // note access the 'doubl' function inside the state, hence context.state.doubl
                        <button onClick={context.state.doubl}>dubl {context.state.counter}</button>
                    </React.Fragment>
                )}
            </MyContext.Consumer>
            // other presentation going here
        </div>
    );
}
```

That's it. Context and provider in a separate file, data and functions accessible from other files.

HTH, Mike